# How to write data.frame into arff using R

Tags: r, weka, arff

Weka can read csv files, however, if csv file's format is not fully satisfy Arff file standard, it may cause some problem. For example, I found loading a time series CSV file to Weka cause errors repeatedly.

There have been some posts on using python to convert csv to arff online, but I think the code is a little lengthy and not always work.

Is there a safer and quick way to convert csv to arff in R?

Answer (score 3):

Simple, use the package RWeka

```
library(RWeka)
write.arff(iris, file = "iris.arff")
```

Comment: Yes, if you use Windows. So far, it seems RWeka is not working for Mac.

Comment: these may of help: http://justrocketscience.com/post/install-rweka-mac, 
http://conjugateprior.org/2014/12/r-java8-osx/

Comment: Thanks, I tried those earlier. but as you can see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_RWeka.html) seems to suggest it is a problem which needs fixed by package creators

Answer (score 2):

For Mac User (as RWeka for mac has not fixed yet):

For CSV file which cannot be loaded to Weka using CSVLoader, use R's foreign library to convert dataset from csv file to arff file

The following R code can convert a timeSeries dataset from csv into an arff file accepted by Weka

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(foreign)  

byd = read.csv('byd_ready.csv')

byd %>% glimpse()

byd = byd %>% mutate(tradeDate = as.Date(tradeDate))

write.arff(byd, file='byd_R1.arff')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package on CRAN:

farff: A Faster 'ARFF' File Reader and Writer