# How to ues write.arff() with R?

Tags: r, rweka

I'm totally new on `R` and `Weka` and `Data mining`. But my tutor ask me to research with RWeka. I've been browsing online about the write. `Arff()` all the information, but still don't know how to use this function correctly:

```
write.arff(x, file, eol = "\n", relation = deparse(substitute(x)))
```

I hope someone can show me how to use the function in more detail and show me some samples using parameters completely.

Comment: please elaborate your question, describe what you're trying to do OR search online

Comment: Thanks, I just want to know how to use the write.arff() function. I have already search https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.arff.html, but I don't know how to other parameters...

Comment: Please type `?write.arff` to get the documentation for the function. It clearly says what each of the four arguments mean. x is the data that you want to write out. file is the name of the file that you want to create.  You probably should just accept the defaults on eol and relation.

Comment: You might also get some help from this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880549/how-to-write-data-frame-into-arff-using-r/40888487#40888487)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can understand how to use "x" and the defaults on eol and relation, but I don't understand the  syntax of the "file".For example, I want to write iris data set into the file "H:/Test", but it prompt an error:Error in file(file, "w") : Unable to open the link
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "w") : Unable to open file 'H:/Test': Permission denied                               so can you tell me how to use the file parameter?Thanks again!